# How to set dynamic text from server side in textbox in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am using MVC 4 with Razor view engine. Here i can get value from client side to server side but now I want to set database values to bind respected controls, server side to client side. But how can we do this....???

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Registration", "Home"))
{
    @Html.Label("User Name: "); @Html.TextBox("txtUserName","");
    @Html.Label("Password: "); @Html.TextBox("txtPassword", "");
    @Html.Label("Email ID: "); @Html.TextBox("txtEmailID", "");
    @Html.Label("Age: "); @Html.TextBox("txtAge", "");
    @Html.Label("Adderss: "); @Html.TextBox("txtAdderss", "");
    @Html.Label("Gender: "); @Html.TextBox("txtGender", "");

       <input type="button" value="Update" />  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use model. Send the model with values from server side to client side.

`//in the model
public class User
{
public string txtUserName { get; set; }
public string txtPassword { get; set; }
public string txtEmailID { get; set; }
public string txtAge { get; set; }
public string txtAdderss { get; set; }
public string txtGender { get; set; }
}

//in the controller
public ActionResult Registration()
{
User userObj = new User(); 
// or you can make a database call and fill the model object 
userObj.txtUserName = "Name";
userObj.txtPassword = "password";
userObj.txtEmailID = "email";
userObj.txtAge = "age";
userObj.txtAdderss = "address";
userObj.txtGender = "gender";
return View(userObj);
}

//in the view
@model Model.User
@using (Html.BeginForm("Registration", "Home"))
{
@Html.Label("User Name: "); @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.txtUserName);
@Html.Label("Password: "); @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.txtPassword);
@Html.Label("Email ID: "); @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.txtEmailID);
@Html.Label("Age: "); @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.txtAge);
@Html.Label("Adderss: "); @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.txtAdderss);
@Html.Label("Gender: ");  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.txtGender);

<input type="button" value="Update" /> }`

`

this link might help you with mvc basics

[link](https://blog.michaelckennedy.net/2012/01/20/building-asp-net-mvc-forms-with-razor/)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a Model to pass values to your view from the Controller.
A quick google search returned this site with [examples](http://chsakell.com/2013/05/02/4-basic-ways-to-pass-data-from-controller-to-view-in-asp-net-mvc/comment-page-1/) of passing data from controller to view.

Comment: Thankx Brother, Your link really help me but I was looking for bind data in textbox.